# Assets.xcassets - Universal not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, assets

I am using Universal for `Assets.xcassets` in the hopes that I only have to create 3 different sizes for each image I use. But, despite `Assets.xcassets` telling me that my images are Universal in the Attributes Inspector, when I test  on my iPad, the images are blurry and aren't as sharp as they are on my iPhone, making me question why there is a Universal option.

I've double checked all my images and they are all correctly sized.

My questions:

1. In the Attributes Inspector, under Universal, there are iPhone and iPad options. In order for my iPad to provide crystal clear images, should I use the iPad option?
2. And if I should: What's the point of the Universal option if it doesn't really do its job?
3. Also if I should: What size images do I use. The iPad option gives me the options of 1x and 2x size images. So, should the size of the 1x image for iPad be the same size as 1x image for Universal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal merely means that this app will run on iPad and iPhone natively. Thus the devices on which your app might run can have a single-resolution, double-resolution, or triple-resolution screen.

If you have checked Universal, accordingly, you should see three slots:

[image]

Your job, therefore, is to make three versions of your image, sized in proportion. If the 1x is 100x100, the 2x should be 200x200 and the 3x should be 300x300. The version in the appropriate slot will be used at runtime in accordance with the screen resolution of the device we're running on.

The asset catalog does not do any image sizing for you. You have to do it beforehand. (I find Graphic Converter a nice utility for this purpose.)

You *could* just supply a 3x image and allow the runtime to size *down* for you, but this is a waste of memory; Apple specifically advises against this in one of the WWDC 2016 videos. So just bite the bullet and make all three image sizes yourself.

Finally:

> when I test on my iPad, the images are blurry and aren't as sharp as they are on my iPhone

Hmm, the only reason I can think of for this is that your app is *not* running natively on the iPad, but is an iPhone app running in "emulation mode" on the iPad. If that's the case, *nothing* you can do is going to make it look really good. It would be better to write your app as a true Universal app. That is a setting that you make when you create the project initially (though it can be changed later by editing the app target).

Comment: In order to make it universal, I tested what device the app was running on, and resized accordingly (iPad's images are 2x bigger than iPhone.) Is this is emulation mode, and if not, how do I test whether it is.

Comment: "I tested what device the app was running on, and resized accordingly (iPad's images are 2x bigger than iPhone." Ah. But in that case you should not be using Universal. You should be using iPad and iPhone and providing separate sets of images (_sets_ of images, in accordance with what I said earlier).